# SSRS Reports need to reuse rdl files from SSRS 2005 (VS 2005) in SSRS 2008 (VS 2008)

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2009, rdl

I initially posted a thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/f76c3170-d6f5-45a5-91c3-21748d15320b). Since I've received no answer, I'm posting here as well.

It's all about Dynamics AX 2009 and SSRS reports built and exported from VS 2005. I have rdl and rdl.data files from a Dynamics AX 2009 SQL Server 2005 ERP environment.

My problem is partially addressed in these threads ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/75a46847-806e-49da-96b5-691e31813f6e), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875252/is-it-possible-to-import-existing-ssrs-reports-in-visual-studio) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183953/how-to-get-visual-studio-2008-to-edit-ssrs-2005-report-projects-w-o-installing-s)).

A similar environment was set by the developers to study the client system with client data with following exceptions

- Database: SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (not 2005)
- Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.50.1600.1 (guess client has old due to sql Server 2005).
- Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Now the only thing I want to do is to somehow get that rdl file (or rdlc file when renamed as directed in some threads) associated to some report project in Visual Studio 2008 / bids so that I can reuse the layout in rdlc file, associate it to some dataset/model (from AX, so I will need queries availability here) and get my report deployed in AX 2009 AOT.

I select the Dynamics AX Reporting project template in the VS 2008. The problem is, once I rename the rdl to rdlc and open it in VS 2008, it starts giving a very good layout as shown in the image as well.

[image]

But all this layout, these fields are useless since the dataset they are bound to is not available. And I find no other means to attach models that I can create in the new report(s)(.moxl file perhaps)

If I do not rename the rdl file, it opens its xml schema as follows:

[image]

I tried this since I found a conversion thread, I changed the schema and saved the file, reopened it and same xml which is useless for me I guess.

What's the role of SSDT, this is available only since VS 2010 I think, is that a must for rdl file conversion as I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)?

How can i reuse this 2005 rdl file or renamed rdlc file which is successfully rendering its layout / design in VS 2008, just need to bind it to AX datasource / query / temp table and I'm done.

Is it not possible at all? Or is it just not the way to do - I have tons of such rdl files and i want to reuse their layout.

Comment: try opening rdl files using MS SQL BIDS 2005 or newer.

Comment: did so, but if u read carefully, i have got the layout, now what i need to do is to bind that rdlc file some how in the .moxl or the report model, how to do that ? Add some new datasource ? How can i bind it to the A queries which are available for any new report that i add from the IDE (VS 2008) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the vanila Visual Studio Report Designer, it separates the Datasets from the Design surface.  The Design surface doesnt care how you got the rows and columns in each Dataset.  So your challenge is probably to create a new Data Source in the Report Designer and then edit the Dataset definitions so that the same columns are produced from your new Data Source.

I havent used SSRS against AX and havent heard of a model or .moxl file. This may complicate your scenario.

Comment: making it more short and precise for you guys, how to link a flat rdl / rdlc file (successfully giving layout as in the snapshot) to a reporting project and bind it to AX dataset / data source

Comment: no sir cause your post was not clear to me, can you provide some repeatable steps which i can do repeat my vs 2008 ?

Comment: Open the report in Visual Studio.  Add the Data Source for AX. Edit each Dataset definition to point to the AX Data Source, and replace the Dataset code with your AX dataset code. Tweak the AX code to produce the same columns as the old code, or tweak your Report Design (e.g. Textbox Expressions, Grouping etc) to suit the AX columns.